# First order taylor expansion formal proof

Tags: asymptotics, finite-differences, pattern-recognition

Studying from Christopher Bishop's Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning book, I came across the following:

$$
\frac{\partial E_n}{\partial w_{ji}^{(l)}} = \frac{E_n(w_{ji}^{(l)} + \epsilon) - E_n(w_{ji}^{(l)})}{\epsilon}
 + O(\epsilon)$$

I am looking for a formal proof of the former using the definition of the big O notation:

$$
f(x) = O(g(x)) \text{ as } x \to a \iff \exists \delta,M\in\mathbb{R}^{++}.\ 0<|x - a|<\delta \implies|f(x)|\leq Mg(x)
$$

Although $E_n$ is, in the context of the book, the error term of a neural network, we can consider $E_n$ as a complicated non-convex function. Since

$$
 E_n= \sum_i(\hat y_i - y_i)^2
$$

and

$$
\hat y_i =\sum_kw_{ji}^{(2)} h\left(\sum_{k'}w_{kk'}^{(1)}x_{k'}\right)
$$

Where $h$ is a non-linear differentiable function.

Which would translate to a proof of the big-O term in a first-order Taylor expansion for any function $f$.

Comment: If you remove all the non-essentials in the equation - all the indices are constant in it - it boils down to this:$$\frac {df}{dx} = \frac{f(x + h) - f(x)}h + O(h)$$ which follows if $f$ is sufficiently regular. Which your later comments indicated are true for the functions under discussion.

Comment: Thanks, @PaulSinclair, but what I am looking for is to have a formal proof of the equation to wrote. Not the statement that it is.

Comment: And you should note I made a comment instead of an answer. But you should also note that my comment amounts to "this is really pretty simple if you remove all the pointless decorations".

Comment: Have you learned Taylor series yet and if so, have you looked back at the proof lately?  It hasn't changed.